# Admin Theme Url Alternates - Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

In admin theme, how can you define url alternates: for example: content-url-admin.cshtml is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, check here: http://orchardpros.net/tickets/9105. JUst keep directory structure and everything seems ok.